# FP in scala Chapter 5. How does the following work

Tags: scala

I see the following example on chapter 5 in FP in scala to drive home non-strictness

```
   val x = Cons(() => expensive(x), tl)
   val h1 = x.headOption
   val h2 = x.headOption
```

and I am trying to understand how

`val x = Cons(() => expensive(x), tl)` works? specifically the `thunk () => expensive(x)`, given x itself is being defined?

Comment: `() => expensive(x)` is a function which takes unit and returns the eval of `expensive(x)` as result. To get the value of the `head` you'll have to invoke it as `head()` basically `closure` https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-closures-in-scala-fp-examples

Comment: thanks for your response! I am familiar with closure and also with thunks.. And I also understand we need to force thunk (in this case head(), which comes from headOption) 
My question is more around, how x (which is being defined) can itself be passed to a method (in this case expensive(x))? I get the part that it is passed by name (and not by value) and the actual evaluation will involve calling headOption

Comment: now that you meantion, didn't notice that bit (should have read more slowly) am just going to assume the author probably mean some other `x`. `val x = someFunction(x)` where `x` type is the same as the function parameter results in `null` (tried in 2.12, 2.13)

Comment: thanks again! 

to be sure, I have tested it out and looks like you will get Null for AnyRef and 0 for AnyVal.

If the function/method is polymorphic such as the one below,
def expensive[A](x: A): A = x

then, while creating a val, the type annotation will be mandatory.. such as
val y: String = expensive(y) 

whereas in the cons, no type annotation was used

val x = Cons(() => expensive(x), tl)

and I find it hard to believe that there is a typo or omission of some sort in the book..